# How to permanently "wire" an EC2 ip address to django in a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html.  I am working with an ubuntu 14.4 instance on amazon EC2. I'm trying to deploy a django app I've developed locally with python3. So far I've got the app working following the tut as long as I manually ssh in , turn on the virtualenv and then turn on uwsgi, using :

```
workon env1
uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/mysite_uwsgi.ini
```

I noticed however  that when I tried to send a request to the app this morning, that I was getting:

```
errno 5 input/output error
```

This was solved my manually sshing in and executing the 2 lines above. I don't understand how this works exactly , but somehow my virtualenv and uwsgi were deactivated after I logged off. I need to keep them active so that all requests can be funneled to my app. I don't know how to do this. Following the tut above , I've modified /etc/rc.local to:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.    

workon myenv
uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/mysite_uwsgi.ini    


exit 0
```

Will this solve my problem. If not what should I do?

Comment: I doubt EC2 instances `sleep` or terminate automatically. You should give `gunicorn` a try, which has a daemon mode so you can disconnect from your SSH connection and still have it running in the background. Very easy to set up too http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [daemonize](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#uwsgi) the process:

```
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings # set an environment variable
pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid # create a pidfile
harakiri = 20 # respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
limit-as = 128 # limit the project to 128 MB
max-requests = 5000 # respawn processes after serving 5000 requests
"uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --daemonize=/var/log/yourproject.log # background the
```

Comment: Thanks, using --daemonize = /var/log/yourproject.log worked for me

Comment: unfortunately no, I think there is an explanation of this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715039/python-interplay-between-lib-site-packages-site-py-and-lib-site-py however

Comment: should look like "uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --daemonize=/var/log/yourproject.log"

Comment: Yes, this was more a note to myself/others.

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the rest of the doc and are ready to run in "emperor" mode, add this to /etc/rc.local before `exit 0`:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

Comment: Hi, I'd love to set up emperor mode, but I ran into a problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903269/uwsgi-importerror-no-module-named-site-on-ubuntu