# Cannot install any packages with pip I got this error ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs'

Tags: python, pip, package, runtime-error

When I try install any packages with pip or use pip I got the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs'
```

an Example:

```
!pip install tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 6, 
    in <module> from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs as _appdirs
    ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs''''
```

Another example:

```
   `pip --version 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
   File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site
    packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 19, in <module>
from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
    File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip._vendor import appdirs as _appdirs
    ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs'
```

How could I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'appdirs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798137/importerror-no-module-named-appdirs)

Comment: No, but now I do know what I did but I got this error: Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Comment: I fixed it. I installed it by Conda       conda install -c conda-forge tweepy and worked.

Answer (score 6):

I also get the same error when using ubuntu. You have to install pip installation first by typing the below command on your terminal.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

After installation, you can now install your requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `pip` is broken.

You can try to reinstall pip - how to do it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917534/pip-broken-on-ubuntu-14-4-after-package-upgrade/28919613#28919613).