# Using virtualenv in VSCode gives ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' but normal terminal does not

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

When using virtualenv in VSCode **integrated terminal** I get the following error when trying to use `pip` or `pip3`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/repo/py-hello/venv/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs as _appdirs
ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

However, this isn't the case when using a regular terminal. I can run pip fine.

I found a few mentions in other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611793/cannot-install-any-packages-with-pip-i-got-this-error-importerror-cannot-import) and [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1675) but neither are helping me.

Comment: Are they the same pip command? What does the `which` command say the paths are?

Comment: Can you show `sys.path` after running python in the terminal?